# Reading in a .txt file with morse code and finding letters with from a tree?

Tags: c, tree, morse-code

'    I need to be able to create a alphabet tree. Then open an example .txt file with `'.'`,`'-'` and `'/'` `'//'`. `'.'` goes to the left of the tree or in this case the rist letters.'-'dash        to the right.
    http://www.skaut.ee/?jutt=10201 - what the tree looks like. '

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

struct MorsePuu {
       char t2ht; 
       struct MorsePuu *punkt, *kriips, *next;
};

static int i;    
char TAHED[32]={' ','E','I','S','H','V','U','F','Ü','A','R','L','Ä','W','P','J','T','N','D','B','X','K','C','Y','M','G','Z','Q','O','Ö','™'};
//creating the "alphabet-tree"
struct MorsePuu *Ehitamine(int N) {
   struct MorsePuu *uus;
   int nl, nr;
   if (N==0) {return NULL;}
   else {
        nl = N / 2;
        nr = N-nl-1;
        uus = malloc(sizeof *uus);
        uus->t2ht = TAHED[i];
        i++;
        uus->punkt = NULL;
        uus->kriips = NULL;
        uus->punkt = Ehitamine(nl);
        uus->kriips = Ehitamine(nr);
        return uus;
        }
 }
 //creating the order of the tree.
  Preorder(struct MorsePuu *JViit) {
    printf("%c",JViit->t2ht);
    if (JViit->punkt != NULL) {
       Preorder(JViit->punkt);}
//      printf("%c",JViit->t2ht); Siin oleks Inorderi väljatrükk
    if (JViit->kriips != NULL) {
       Preorder(JViit->kriips);}
//      printf("%c",JViit->t2ht);  Ja siin oleks Postorderi väljatrükk
 }



main(void) {
    struct MorsePuu *morse, *abi;    
    char rida[128];
    FILE *fm=NULL;

    printf("Käigepealt tuleb morsepuu ?les ehitada!");
    i = 0;
    morse=Ehitamine(31);
    printf("Puu väljatrükk preorder järjekorras.\n");
    Preorder(morse);
    printf("%c",morse);

    //opening the file . Contents e.g .-/.// return ie. // stops it.
    fm = fopen("morse1.txt", "r");


    fgets(rida, 128, fm);
    printf("\n %s", rida);    

    fclose(fm);
    //this is where the reading and changing loop crashers.
    /*  
    for(i=0; i<strlen(rida); i++){
       if(rida[i]=='/'){

      }
       if(rida[i] == '.'){
          //printf();
          abi=abi->punkt;     
       }
       if(rida[i]== '-'){
          abi=abi->kriips;          
         }
      }
  */ 
  }
```

The problem starts from the last  loop. The letter tree is created but i am not able to     search the letter from the tree.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't allocate any memory for `*abi` here

```
main(void) {
struct MorsePuu *morse, *abi;    
char rida[128];
FILE *fm=NULL;
```

Abi is a pointer to struct MorsePuu, it points to a random location and when you use it later you cause undefined behaviour at line `abi=abi->punkt`.

You have to add a line

```
abi = malloc( sizeof( struct MorsePuu )) ;
```